# issue with concurrent int read and write

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Can somebody help me understand why below program is exiting?
One thread is updating i alternatively with 1 and 2.
Another thread is reading i and will exit if i value is neither 1 nor 2.
Actually below program should not exit but it exits printing either 1 or 2.

```
static volatile int i = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                i = (i == 1 ? 2 : 1);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (i != 1 && i != 2) {
                    System.out.println("i=" + i);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: This could be a good question for people who are new in Java :)

Answer (score 3):

because in the  `if (i != 1 && i != 2)` statement there are two check instructions, they are evaluated sequentially, so it is possible that when the `i != 1` was invoked, the `i` has value `2` so it evaluated to `false` and when `i != 2` was invoked `i` has been switched back to value `1` by the switching thread, so it also evaluated to `false` as a consequence the whole `if (i != 1 && i != 2)` evaluated to false, because evaluation of `if` in java is not atomic.

Comment: to put it other words, in the line checking `i != 1 && i != 2` when the first was tested the value was 2 it passed, but in the very moment before the program checked the second one, the other thread switched it to 1 so the second part passed as well, and most probably when it wrote out it had a third state.

Comment: > modification to value of an integer in java is not atomic - I've always thought that it is atomic if we're talking about int (as in code provided). Modification of long is indeed nonatomic.

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine you are at `if (i != 1 && i != 2)`. There are two separate actions:

1. `read i and compare to 1`
2. `read i and compare to 2`

Since `i` is volatile, the compiler/VM need to pull both times from memory. There is a scenario where (1) reads `2` and (2) reads `1`. In that case, you will get into the `System.exit`.

Comment: it works well without volatile as well, anyways it surely helps to make some gap between the two checks

Comment: Yes, you're right it does. With volatile, it is very predictable to happen.